# Calculate weighted average with numbers and weights stored in two arrays

Tags: swift, math

There are already questions on Stack Overflow on how to calculate weighted mean of an `[Int:Int]` dictionary, including fancy ways using `reduce`. But I now have the numbers and weights stored in two arrays. The numbers are not guaranteed to be identical. **What is the *Swift* way to do this? Is it possible using Swift features like `reduce`? I wish there is a way that does not use a `for` loop.** Thanks!

```
let numbers = [1, 2, 4, 3, 2]
let weights = [10, 20, 30, 15, 25]
```

Comment: The short answer is don't store the numbers and their weights in separate arrays. That's fragile. Create a struct that contains a value and a weight, and then use an array of those structs.

Comment: @DuncanC Thanks for the heads up! It's just the numbers and weights loaded into the code as two arrays.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No `for` loops:

```
func weightedAverage(values: [Double], weights: [Double]) -> Double {
    precondition(values.count > 0 && values.count == weights.count)

    let totalWeight = weights.reduce(0.0, +)
    precondition(totalWeight > 0)

    return zip(values, weights)
            .map { $0 * $1 }
            .reduce(0.0, +) / totalWeight
}

let avg = weightedAverage(values: [1, 2, 4, 3, 2], weights: [10, 20, 30, 15, 25])
print(avg)
```

Comment: Seems quite *swifty*! Is the usage of `precondition` rather than `guard` a style or preference, or that is how we should use it? Because I often see people use `guard`.

Comment: Use this function to detect conditions that must prevent the program from proceeding, even in shipping code.
In playgrounds and -Onone builds (the default for Xcode’s Debug configuration): If condition evaluates to false, stop program execution in a debuggable state after printing message.
In -O builds (the default for Xcode’s Release configuration): If condition evaluates to false, stop program execution.
In -Ounchecked builds, condition is not evaluated, but the optimizer may assume that it always evaluates to true. Failure to satisfy that assumption is a serious programming error.

Comment: A `precondition` is used when there is no way to proceed if the conditions are not met. More succinct than `guard ... { fatalError(...) }`

Answer (score 1):

This the implementation using swifty way:

```
let numbers = [14.424, 14.421, 14.417, 14.413, 14.41]
let weights = [3058.0, 8826.0, 56705.0, 30657.0, 12984.0]
let sum = weights.reduce(0, {$0 + $1})
let a = numbers.enumerated().map { (arg) -> Double in

    let (index, element) = arg

    return Double(element * weights[index] / sum)
}.reduce(0, {$0 + $1})
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Basically, the `index` used in a `for` loop is transferred to the `map()` after `enumerated()`. Strictly speaking, the `index` is still being handled explicitly in the code.

Answer (score 0):

If you meant average:

```
let numbers = [1, 2, 4, 3, 2]
let weights = [10, 20, 30, 15, 25]

var average = 0
var sum = 0

weights.forEach { (num) in
    average += num
}

for i in 0...numbers.count-1 {
    sum += (numbers[i] * weights[i])
}

var finalValue = sum/average

print(finalValue)
```

Comment: Does this mean I still have to use a `for` loop?

Comment: If you use a method to do this, this method made a `for loop`. Just copy and paste.

Answer (score 0):

You could use zip and reduce:

```
let numbers: [Double] = [1,  2,   4,  3,  2]
let weights: [Double] = [10, 20, 30, 15, 25]

let totalWeights = weights.reduce(0, { $0 + $1 } )
let combined: [(value: Double, weight: Double)] = Array(zip(numbers, weights))
let weightedTotal = combined.reduce(0.0, { $0 + $1.value * $1.weight } )
let weightedAverage = weightedTotal/Double(numbers.count)/totalWeights
print(weightedAverage)
```